# Is there a javascript solution for dependent select fields?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to set up a dependent field based on a referral select field. If one of the referral options are selected, I would like for my referral name field to appear in the form.

I have tried using javascript to solve for this issue, but keep getting hung up when trying to add additional values for the select field.

```
<div class="smartcapture-controls"><div class="sc-formfield-label"><label 
for="Hear About">How Did you Hear About Us? *</label></div>
<div class="sc-formfield-input">
 <select id="master-dependent" name="Hear About" data-field-type="Text" 
required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this 
field.">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>

  <option value="Through ICC">Through ICC</option>

  <option value="Through Triumph Business Capital">Through Triumph 
Business Capital</option>

  <option value="Through Another Triumph Employee">Through Another 
Triumph Employee</option>

  <option value="Through a Triumph Insurance Client">Through a Triumph 
Insurance Client</option>

  <option value="Online Search">Online Search</option>

  <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>

 </select>
</div>
</div>
```

If any of the first 4 options are selected, I would like for it to display my referral field below

```
<div id="dependent" style="display:none;" class="smartcapture-controls"> 
 <div class="sc-formfield-label"><label for="Referral Name">Referral Name * 
 </label></div>
<div class="sc-formfield-input"><input type="text" name="Referral Name" 
data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this field."></div>
</div>
```

This was the code I was trying below, but cannot seem to get my referral field to populate

```
<script>
function showHideReferral() {
    if(document.getElementByID("master-dependent").value=="Through ICC") {
        document.getElementById("dependent").style.display="block";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("dependent").style.display="none";
    }
}

</script>
```

The expected result is to have the referral field populate in the form if any of the first 4 options are selected. But currently, my referral field stays hidden no matter the selection.

Comment: Where is the call to `showHideReferral()`?

Comment: yes, add `onchange="showHideReferral()"` to the select tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you call your show hide `function` in the `onchange` event, that you fix typos like `getElementByID` (correct is `getElementById` instead) and that your logic is correct. This is a tested solution:

```js
  function showHideReferral() {
        if(document.getElementById("master-dependent").value.indexOf("Through") == 0) {
            document.getElementById("dependent").style.display="block";
    
        } else {
            document.getElementById("dependent").style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="smartcapture-controls"><div class="sc-formfield-label"><label 
    for="Hear About">How Did you Hear About Us? *</label></div>
    <div class="sc-formfield-input">
     <select onchange="showHideReferral()" id="master-dependent" name="Hear About" data-field-type="Text" 
    required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this 
    field.">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    
      <option value="Through ICC">Through ICC</option>
    
      <option value="Through Triumph Business Capital">Through Triumph 
    Business Capital</option>
    
      <option value="Through Another Triumph Employee">Through Another 
    Triumph Employee</option>
    
      <option value="Through a Triumph Insurance Client">Through a Triumph 
    Insurance Client</option>
    
      <option value="Online Search">Online Search</option>
    
      <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
    
     </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="dependent" style="display:none;" class="smartcapture-controls"> 
     <div class="sc-formfield-label"><label for="Referral Name">Referral Name * 
     </label></div>
    <div class="sc-formfield-input"><input type="text" name="Referral Name" 
    data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this field."></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I figured it was something simple I was forgetting. This solution worked for me, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @RunRabbit I am happy the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

add `onchange="showHideReferral(this)"` to `select` and

```
function showHideReferral(select) {
  let v = ["","Social Media","Online Search"];

  dependent.style.display = v.includes(select.value) ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```js
function showHideReferral(select) {
  let v = ["","Social Media","Online Search"];
  
  dependent.style.display = v.includes(select.value) ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="smartcapture-controls">
  <div class="sc-formfield-label"><label for="Hear About">How Did you Hear About Us? *</label></div>
  <div class="sc-formfield-input">
    <select id="master-dependent" name="Hear About" data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this 
field." onchange="showHideReferral(this)">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>

      <option value="Through ICC">Through ICC</option>

      <option value="Through Triumph Business Capital">Through Triumph Business Capital</option>

      <option value="Through Another Triumph Employee">Through Another Triumph Employee</option>

      <option value="Through a Triumph Insurance Client">Through a Triumph Insurance Client</option>

      <option value="Online Search">Online Search</option>

      <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>




<div id="dependent" style="display:none;" class="smartcapture-controls">
  <div class="sc-formfield-label"><label for="Referral Name">Referral Name * 
 </label></div>
  <div class="sc-formfield-input"><input type="text" name="Referral Name" data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this field."></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot the first option. Please add that to your array and let me know about it.

Comment: You are right, It is not clear but probably OP w wants first 4 non-empty options to display additional field - answer updated

Comment: This is a nice answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the select box as below and do the compare

```
<script>
function showHideReferral() {
    *if(document.getElementByID("master-dependent").options[e.selectedIndex].value=="Through ICC"){*
        document.getElementById("dependent").style.display="block";

    } else {
       document.getElementById("dependent").style.display="none";
    }
}
```